# Remove Seconds from TimeSpan Duration()

Tags: c#, timespan, duration

I want to remove only the seconds part of the output which comes as my **ActualWorkedHours** variable [HH:mm:ss].

This is my C# code:

```cs
    ActualWorkedHours =(shiftAttendanceBo.ActOutDateTime.Value.Subtract(shiftAttendanceBo.ActInDateTime.Value).Duration().ToString()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on .Net 4, then you can use `ToString(@"hh\:mm")`

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan ts = (shiftAttendanceBo.ActOutDateTime.Value.Subtract(shiftAttendanceBo.ActInDateTime.Value).Duration()
ActualWorkedHours = (ts - new TimeSpan(0, 0, ts.Seconds)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(10,30,15);
    Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm"));
```